# Visual Studio Plug-in that can tell the Application Pool name of w3wp.exe when debugging

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, application-pool, w3wp

Is there any plug-in for Visual Studio that can display the associated Application Pool name for those w3wp processes when debugging them with "Attach to Process..." ?

Usually I have to do following steps before debugging:

c:> `\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list wps`

then I get the process id for the Application Pool I want to debug, and then attach it in the Attach to Process window.

I feel it will be very pleasure if there's a plug in can do this automatically, but didn't find any such thing after Googled.

Comment: I'm asking this because usually I have a lot of w3wp process running on my dev machine, also some Visual studio instances for different projects. these projects are interacting with WCF.

Comment: I was just about to ask about identification of which w3 process was which. Cheers for reading my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a macro—see my answer to [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654406/in-vs2010-is-there-a-way-to-know-which-application-pool-a-given-w3wp-exe-is-serv/4892932#4892932).  I am practically always attaching to one of a few specific Application Pools, so I’ve made buttons to attach to those specifically in one click.  If you really want to choose from a dynamic list each time you’ll just have to build that dialog, but you can lift from my macro code to get the list.