# How can i diagnose IIS pushing the CPU to 100% usage?

Tags: asp.net, iis, cpu-usage

I have a web server with more than a few ASP.NET sites running on it. Every so often, i notice that IIS is pushing the server's CPU to 100%. The sites share application pools, per .NET version they are running.

What i'm looking for is a way to be able to pinpoint which site it is that is doing this, using some tool. If that tool happened to get down into the code to show it, that would also be nice. If not, i'm happy just knowing which site is causing the issue.

I've already tried using ANTS. However, with ANTS you need to know which site it is, and then have it running and waiting on said CPU-crashing web app. Not perfectly ideal.

Any experience/ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use task manager to get the PID of the process that is taking all of the CPU, then use the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748927/iis-application-pool-pid) to match the PID to the web site.

Comment: So if i used this method, i would have to split all sites out into separate app pools?

Comment: Or do a binary search. Split your apps into two pools. When you see one go wonky, take half of those apps and put them in the other pool. When you see one go wonky, ....

Answer (score 2):

Check the IIS Debug Diagnostics tool http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919790,

another approach,  break each site into different app pools and then watch the app pools in Task Manager to see the memory usage.

Comment: @Irish - there's a new version (1.2) in beta that supports 64 bit windows better. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2010/09/30/debug-diag-1-2-beta.aspx you need to email the team (dbgdiag (at) microsoft.com) to get a copy. But they do reply pretty quick (under 1hr for me).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to David's (correct) answer, once you've identified the WS in question, VS2010 with team tools has some fantastic performance analysis stuff under the "Analyze" menu. With the tools in there, you should be able to narrow your problems down to specific lines of code in no time.

It's stupidly simple to use the Performance Analysis Wizard - just point it at the project in question, let it launch, run through various actions on the site and it will give you every metric you need to find your problem (it even puts flame icons next to the CPU-intensive code in the editor)

Answer (score 0):

Low-tech answer:
+ Use the Task Manager to identify the loaded worker process.
+ Use c:\windows\system32\issapp.vbs to identify the app pool name of the loaded process
(alternatively, DebugDiag does the same thing more easily, if you're familiar with that tool. There's a column header for App Pool name on the Process Tab.)
+ Create new app pools and split your apps between them until you can isolate the app causing the problem into an app pool all by itself.

More technical answer:
+ Use the Task Manager to identify the
   loaded worker process.  Hang dump
   that worker process using DebugDiag
   or ADPlus -hang -p  (a part of
   Debugging Tools for Windows, both
   free downloads from Microsoft)
+ DebugDiag can pre-analyze the hang
   dump for you, and may just give you
   all the clues you need. That's a
   medium tech solution that often
   works. You'll want to look at the
   process tab and right click on the
   offending process. Choose "Full Usermode
   Dump" or something like that. Find
   the created dump file at c:\Program
   Files\DebugDiag\Logs\Misc*.dmp and
   double-click it to see the
   pre-analysis.
+ If DebugDiag doesn't
   give you enough clues, then WinDBG
   can certainly tell you what you need
   to know, though it's an arcane and
   difficult tool to even begin with,
   much less master. (It's also a whole
   lot of fun. I highly recommend it if you're an admin and frequently asked such questions. )