# Fire or Not Exception on Debug

Tags: c#

I have a class Dispatcher with a method Send as follows:

```
public class Dispatcher : IDispatcher {

  public void Send(Order order) {
    Type type = typeof(IOrderHandler<>).MakeGenericType(order.GetType());
    IOrderHandler handler = (IOrderHandler)ObjectFactory.GetInstance(type);

    try {
      handler.Handle(order);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
      ILogger logger = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ILogger>();
      logger.Send(exception);
    }

  }

} // Send
```

I am handling orders and catching exceptions ...

When I am debugging I would like to still fire the exception.

How can I do this?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: You would like to still *fire* the exception? Are you saying you want to be notified by the IDE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add this line to your catch block:

```
 if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) throw;
```

Comment: +1, This is a much better approach in IDE, Good to know about `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached`

Comment: I don't get it ... With this the exception will allways be fire in debug or release ... But when I have the site on the server what will happen?

Comment: @MDMoura, this only deals when you are debugging in Visual studio, when you have site on server, there wouldn't be any debugger attached. Unless you decide to [attach one ....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848987/attach-debugger-to-iis-instance)

Comment: Ah, got it! So your suggestion is great! I was trying [Conditional("DEBUG")] on an extra method which would fire the exception but I wasn't getting the point of origin. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can add the following in your catch block:

```
#if DEBUG
                throw;
#endif
```

So your code would look like:

```
            try
            {
                handler.Handle(order);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                ILogger logger = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ILogger>();
                logger.Send(exception);
#if DEBUG
                throw;
#endif
            }
```

If you want the exception notification in IDE during debugging in `Release` configuration, then use @Hans Passant's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19324404/961113), because that will let you know about the exception for both `Release` and `Debug` configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Well, based on the fact that you'd like the exception to still be thrown, *but only when debugging*, you could do this:

1. Open the `Debug` menu and choose `Exceptions`.
2. When the dialog loads, tick the check box next to `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` under the `Thrown` heading.

This will cause you to get a first chance exception. What that means is you'll be notified by the IDE, when debugging, and you'll get a chance to handle it **before** processing continues. This will actually let you see it before it even gets logged.

What's more, you can actually unselect exceptions you don't want with this approach because they are broken down by exception type underneath the `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` grouping.

[More detail...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d14azbfh.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Debug > Exception and check the CLR exceptions for "thrown", this will take you right there. alternatively place a breakpoint on the catch block.