# How to debug two web site projects that are in different solutions?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, vs-web-site-project

I have a solution A with a web site project that it needs to call another web site project B that is in another solution. I mean different visual studio instances

I don't know how to attach them to debug them at the same time like in a single trace.

Does anyone knows how can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: You can't make it single trace, since you have opened each project in different instance of visual studio. But if you set different application pool for each web site, then you can start debug on both project at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using two running Visual Studios:

You set up one of the projects in IIS and the other you can run out of Visual Studio directly then you can debug in both.

On the first project (the one running in IIS) you can 'Attach to a process' and attach to the w3wp worker process. See this:

[Attach Debugger to IIS instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848987/attach-debugger-to-iis-instance)

Then in the second project just run the project using Debug --> Start Debugging option from the VS menu.

Optionally you can run them both out of IIS and attach to both processes.

Make sure you have debug allowed in your web.config files.

Answer (score 0):

What i can think of is, you can deploy project B with pdb file onto a server and attach remote debugger to that server.