# start multiple projects in different solutions in visual studio 2019

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2019

i have two WEB APIs core in different solutions one for authentication and another one for the app, there is a way to run them both when i click on run the App API?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can debug one project on VS and then use **Attach to process** to attach another process of the project so that we can debug both of them at same time.

**First**, For **Project A**, you can first set Project A on IIS(publish to your local IIS). Besides, you can also refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis).

**Then**, Open **Project B** on VS, click **Start Debugging** and then click **Attach to Process** under **Debug** menu TO attach the IIS process of **Project A**. Mostly like `w3wp.exe`, `aspnet_wp.exe`. More info about the IIS process, you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-find-the-name-of-the-aspnet-process?view=vs-2019).

**Note**: you should check `Show processes from all users` checkbox in the bottom left corner.

There is [a similar issue about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47215115/how-to-debug-two-web-site-projects-that-are-in-different-solutions).