# IIS CRM 2011 web service invocation issue

Tags: wcf, web-services, iis-7, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I had a simple program , a asp.net website in which i added a webservice

One of the web  methods accessed a CRM `

```
 [WebMethod]
public bool RecordExists (String projectName)
{
    var service = GetService("http://localhost/EventoCorp/");

    Entity project = new Entity("new_project");

    /*PROJECT DETAILS*/
    project.Attributes["new_name"] = projectName;
    var request = new RetrieveDuplicatesRequest
    {
        BusinessEntity = project,
        MatchingEntityName = "new_project",
        PagingInfo = new PagingInfo() { PageNumber = 1, Count = 50 }
    };

    Console.WriteLine("Retrieving duplicates");
    var response = service.Execute(request);
    EntityCollection collection = (EntityCollection)response.Results["DuplicateCollection"];

    return collection.Entities.Count > 1 ? true : false;
}
```

When I press F5. the project runs fine  . I invoke this record exists method , and it correctly brings data from the CRM 2011

However when i deploy this application on IIS 7.5 . I get greeted by this terribly uninformative exception

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the &lt;serviceDebug&gt; configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.
```

Server stack trace:

```
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

I am a CRM 2011 noob  . No idea what is going on . Please help me

Comment: Could you enable `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults` in the Web.config file and then open your service application in your browser? This will show the exact error and clarify the problem. Or you could check the exception details in the Event Viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception happens in the client you use when trying to connect your web service. It says only that unhandled exception happened on server side, but has no information about exception. Also there is advice to enable `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults` in order to pass to the client unhandled exception details. But there is also other way to see what is going on, it's [attach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210250/how-do-i-attach-the-debugger-to-iis-instead-of-asp-net-development-server) to IIS process and debug your web service.
Also it would be better add exception handling to your code, because now code is completely unsafe. Different exceptions can happen when you are accessing CRM, like authentication exception etc. Also you can just get null instead of collection you suppose to be there.
When you deploying this code to IIS authentication issues are possible, since IIS is working under NETWORK SERVICE account. And in case if CRM uses Windows Authentication it's possible your request will not be authorized.