# method is aborted on soap call

Tags: c#, soap, methods

What I am trying is to use a soap call to send and retrieve information between two web applications. I have added a service reference and now in my code I am trying to use the soap client to make a call.

(in my code I used a 'using' as to not need to specify the namespace in the next line of code)

```
ResourceSoapClient resourceSoapClient = new ResourceSoapClient("ResourceSoap");
```

after this line of code I spend some lines of codes to acquire the data that needs to be sent and then I use the resourceSoapClient object to make a call to it:

```
resourceSoapClient.SendResource(id, resourceData);
```

The problem I have however is that immediately after the creating of 'resourceSoapClient' the method is aborted and nothing of the code that follows is executed. As I step through the method while debugging it acts like just hitting F5 to continue running but no further code is stepped through although I step into or step over. I don't understand what goes wrong here. I hope one of you can help me?

Comment: Why are you passing the "ResourceSoap" string into the constructor?

Comment: If you could add the other Project into your main project, I think you  can have a successful debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How do I attach the debugger to IIS instead of ASP.NET Development Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210250/how-do-i-attach-the-debugger-to-iis-instead-of-asp-net-development-server) try it, please.

VS -> Tools -> Attach to Process ( IIS Process ). Then you can debug your web services.

or use standard WCF Test Client 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure that the WCF test client is going to help with a SOAP issue in this case. Could you add more details clarifying why you think that might help?

Comment: I don't use a WCF service. Btw due to busy schedule I haven't been able to test the given answers yet. Is there a way to extend this bounty? Otherwise I'd have to give a reward  to someone without having seen it working.

Comment: well, what do you use?