# Debug dll of website running under IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have c# class library that it is a part of a big web site. After build, generated dll file copy to bin folder automatically by post-build event command line:

```
copy $(TargetPath) "C:\MyWebSite\bin"
```

My web site run under IIS and I want to debug my class library that its in a separated solution. How can I debug it?

Comment: Please try to use the search for something like "debug asp.net site in iis", which will yield results like [How do I attach the debugger to IIS instead of ASP.NET Development Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210250/how-do-i-attach-the-debugger-to-iis-instead-of-asp-net-development-server). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In solution with your DLL which you want to debug, set break point and choose from menu `Debug` - `Attach to Process...`, then choose w3wc process with your site pool

Comment: So I did, first ensuring that all projects where up to date with respect to build version. Then the breakpoint says: "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.". Any ideas?

Comment: Did you copy *.pdb to output?

Comment: I had to uncheck `Enable Just My Code`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457346.aspx