# Debugging 2 projects locally

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I have a Visual Studio solution that has a main web project and another secondary project that is an application under main.

The solution runs fine in production when published to IIS, but I'm having issues trying to debug locally.

Both are setup in Visual studio to run on different ports under localhost.

I can start the main web app in debug mode, but how do I start the other app so I can debug the whole solution?

Thanks!

Comment: attach the debuger extra to the IIS process something with W3SVC

Comment: @tire0011 I'm not exactly sure what you mean....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210250/how-do-i-attach-the-debugger-to-iis-instead-of-asp-net-development-server second answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can start the main web app in debug mode, but how do I start the other app so I can debug the whole solution?

To achieve this, you can select **Multiple startup projects** on the Property Pages, please Go to Solution ->Properties -> Startup Project:

[image]

Hope this can help you.