# Accessing ASP.NET Development Server from another pc on the network

Tags: asp.net, cross-browser, virtual-pc, remote-access

I would like to test my web app in other browsers. I have installed Virtual PC to do just that. the ASP.NET development server does not allow remote connections so the virtual pc (another computer on the network) cannot access the website.

I found [this](http://forums.asp.net/p/983797/1264377.aspx) post that was started but there was no solution.

I understand that using localhost will not work. I heard about using the machines ip, but how do I get that correct ip? Look at my lynksys router admin?

If I were to get as far as getting my IP, im sure that the asp.net dev server does not allow remote connections. How do I enable it to do so?

Comment: It that simple: just check out the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7394935/717732 and setup yourself a similar tunnel

Comment: SharpProxy works really well https://github.com/jocull/SharpProxy

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm making some guesses about your setup here so bear with:

If your virtual machine is XP Professional, Vista Business, Windows 7 Professional or better, then you should be able to run IIS locally on the development machine and access that webserver from another machine which is on the same network via the virtual machine's name.

Likewise, if you're doing development on a real machine and would like to use different virtual machines to access the web application, you should make sure that you have IIS installed, create a new website in IIS and you should be to browse to the web application via machine name from your virtual machines.

Either way, don't try to use the builtin web server from Visual Studio, just publish your site to IIS and work with it that way.

Good luck and hope this helps some.

Comment: Hi Chris, Without IIS, its also possible to host using WebDev and IISExpress, in that case we are not able to access via remote machine; Any idea in this case?

Comment: Not a chance without IIS.

Answer (score 34):

The answer is: **no**(*). You cannot access the ASP.NET Development Server on one machine from another, even if you open the Windows firewall TCP port.

From the MSDN article [**"Web Servers in Visual Web Developer**"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> It is specifically built to serve, or run, ASP.NET Web pages under the local host scenario (browsing from the same computer as the Web server).
>
> In other words, the ASP.NET Development Server will serve pages to browser requests on the local computer. It will not serve pages to another computer. Additionally, it will not serve files that are outside of the application scope.

(*) You'll have to run your site from your locally installed IIS... or do the nice hack using some freeware described in this blog post:

**[iPhone Accessing the Visual Studio ASP.NET Development Server](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/jimw/archive/2010/08/18/iphone-accessing-the-visual-studio-asp-net-development-server-windows-7-update.aspx)**

> Use [SPI Port Forward](http://download.cnet.com/SPI-Port-Forward/3000-2651_4-10764348.html) to accept the device connections do the following:
>
> Set  "Local port" to the port number the device will connect on, I usually use 8080 out of habit
>   Set  "Remote host" to localhost
>   Set "Remote port" to the ASP.NET Dev Server Port

Click the "Activate" button to start accepting connections

*(note: make sure you've started the program with admin rights)*

Answer (score 8):

Setup a portforwarding using RINETD
Deatils here: http://blog.waynehartman.com/articles/218.aspx

Comment: tried on Win7 but all I get is 'couldn't bind to address x.x.x.x. port yyyy' whichever IPs and port numbers I try

Answer (score 7):

Another answer if you don't want to use IIS (or tunnels): https://stackoverflow.com/a/12008223/1552178

> Use fiddler or similar on your host - set your browser on the client
>   VM to use the proxy then just use localhost:dev_port as usual on the
>   client.
>
> All requests from the client goto the proxy on your dev machine which
>   routes to localhost on the dev machine and the ASP.net dev server
>   thinks the request is from your dev machine!

Comment: Surely this should be the top answer, everyone has already got this installed. Thanks. (you have to allow remote connection inside fiddler though).

Answer (score 4):

I am answering this old question to help people to make it work **without IIS**.

**1. First Step**

You have to download [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Once Fiddler is downloaded and installed, open it.

Go in *Tools-> Fiddler Option-> Connection tab-> And check "Allow remote computers to connect"* :

[image]

Restart Fiddler.

**2. Second Step**

After this, in **the other PC on the network OR the VM**, *open internet explorer-> Internet Options-> Connection Tab-> Lan Settings-> Check "Use a proxy server for your LAN"* :

[image]

1. The adress is the IP adress of your DEV machine.
2. And put the port 8888

Now, you can access the ASP.NET Web Server from another PC on the network (maybe you have, more config to do, like firewall, unrestricted port, etc, but this is a good start) !

To access it ->  http://localhost.:54814

- Don't forget the additional point after "localhost" ! (Overwrite the local localhost)
- The port, "54814" in my case, is the ASP.NET Web Server port.

**NOTE :**

- To test if the proxy work, you can try this : http://localhost.:8888
- Maybe I forgot to point out some configurations, but it always depend of the network infrastructure.

Comment: i have tried the above
but it is show
The proxy server is refusing connections

Comment: Did you check "Allow computer connection" ?

Comment: which conection i have to allow on computer??

Comment: Step 1 : Once Fiddler is downloaded and installed, open it.

Go in Tools-> Fiddler Option-> Connection tab-> And check "Allow remote computers to connect" :

Answer (score 1):

## Working solution for Linux

This should work if you're running an ASP.NET Dev Server on Windows in a VM or on another host and you want to access it from Linux

### On Windows machine

For some reason you cannot connect directly to the ASP.NET dev server port, you need to proxy it locally first:

> Use [SPI Port Forward](http://download.cnet.com/SPI-Port-Forward/3000-2651_4-10764348.html) to accept the device connections do the following:
>
> Set  "Local port" to the port number the device will connect on, such as 8089
>   Set  "Remote host" to localhost
>   Set "Remote port" to the ASP.NET Dev Server Port

Click the "Activate" button to start accepting connections

*(note: make sure you've started the program with admin rights)*

### On Linux machine

Locally forward localhost port 8089 to the windows IP (replace `GUEST_IP_HERE` with the correct ip):

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -m addrtype --src-type LOCAL --dst-type LOCAL -p tcp --dport 8089 -j DNAT --to-destination GUEST_IP_HERE:8089
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m addrtype --src-type LOCAL --dst-type UNICAST -j MASQUERADE
```

This is needed because the dev server specifically looks for localhost in the request and will not respond to `http://GUEST_IP_HERE:8089` from the host

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following that i expected to enable current .net framework [ core / x-platform ] 6.0 release provided asp.net development web server access at least from other machines on local subnet w/o needing to use any 3rd party software enable the port forwarding/proxy to localhost only exposed web server.

I was able to launch the asp.net development web server from windows wsl [ windows subsystem for linux ] distro session and access it using the windows host wi-fi adapter ip address but not from another machine on my subnet, e.g. a vmware linux install operating in bridge mode.  It did work if i switched vmware linux install to nat mode.

Any thoughts on why this doesn't allow other hosts access as i expected it would?

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=<tcp port for non-localhost access allowed/enabled in windows firewall> listenaddress=0.0.0.0 < or windows wired/wifi ipaddress > connectport=<tcp port for localhost access to asp.net development web server> connectaddress=localhost 

e.g. netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=4430 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=7146 connectaddress=localhost & netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=8080 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=5038 connectaddress=localhost 

netsh interface portproxy show all 

// for %i in ( 4430, 8080 ) do ( netsh interface portproxy delete v4tov4 listenport=%i listenaddress=0.0.0.0 )

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Asp.Net Development Web Server Listeners to Expose" dir=in protocol=tcp localport=<csv list of tcp ports allowed/enabled in windows firewall> profile=private|any remoteip=localsubnet|any action=allow [ enable=yes ]

e.g. netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Asp.Net Development Web Server Listeners to Expose" dir=in protocol=tcp localport=4430,8080 profile=private remoteip=localsubnet action=allow

netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name="Asp.Net Development Web Server Listeners to Expose" [ or wf.msc | inbound rules ]

// netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name="Asp.Net Development Web Server Listeners to Expose"
```

Answer (score 0):

year 2022:

After trying everything on asp.net core .NET 6 side and failed I have found
https://mitmproxy.org/

```
mitmproxy --mode reverse:https://localhost:7053 --ssl-insecure
```

covers my use case.

on phone and other devices access with `http://{your-pc-ip}:8080`

Answer (score -4):

Open a command prompt and type; "ipconfig" this will give you your machines IP address.

If you disable your firewall (for the asp.net dev port at least) you should be able to type into the virtual PC's browser http://192.168.1.3:3243/default.aspx

Comment: This doesn't work. It's not that simple. The Development Server is designed to accept only connection from the same machine.