# Access development ASP.NET web app from a static IP address

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, web-applications, static-ip-address

I'm running Visual Studio 2010 on a Windows 7 Ultimate machine. This computer is connected to a router with a static IP address. The IP address is currently used for a remote DVR service on one of the ports, and it can be accessed from any web browser.

I used VS2010 to develop an ASP.NET web application and can currently view it in a web browser by starting a debugging session in VS2010 that fires up a "development IIS server emulator."

So I was curious, can I access my web app from the Internet using the same static IP address and maybe a different port?

PS. I need this for the purpose of demoing it.

Comment: [Take a look at this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918/can-i-access-asp-net-development-server-in-an-intranet)

Comment: Very nice. Thank you. I didn't know that one can install IIS on a Windows 7 machine?