# Getting ASP.NET site publicly available

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

I have used the solution provided by this thread: [Can I access ASP.NET Development server in an intranet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918/can-i-access-asp-net-development-server-in-an-intranet)

I have tried both JavaTCPtunnel and Pocketsoap TCP trace, but they both return Bad Request - Inavlid hostname. I can see that a connection is made, but still this error is returned.

Router and firewall are both forwarded.

Do I need to setup something in the IIS dev server? Why does this work for everyone but not for me?

Comment: Why not use IIS Express instead?

Comment: I have IIS 8.0 Express

Comment: IIS Express by default has an HTTP binding that just listens on localhost. You don't need to worry about tunneling or that stuff - just set IIS express to bind on a host name other than localhost (such as `*` or your machine name). This post explains how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709014/using-custom-domains-with-iis-express

Comment: @vcsjones thank you for this useful tip! However I get stuck at step 2. I have entered the adress of a site that points to my localhost. But this adress is not valid.. What can I do about that?