# Deploying the asp.net code without publishing on a server

Tags: asp.net, web-deployment

Can I use an asp.net web application without publishing it.?
My problem is I have an application on a server which i access using URL such as 192.168.1.2 or something like that. Do I have to compulsorily publish it or I can use my normal build also for hosting a website on a server and let it be used in a LAN.?

Comment: @zey : Say if i don't have IIS.? Can I still deploy the code over LAN..??

Comment: Follow this link , http://stackoverflow.com/a/7394935/1427849 :) But I suggest you should use `IIS` . If you change your mind to use `IIS` , I'll help you friend :)

Comment: @zey : Thanks a lot zey. I have been using IIS since 1 year. I am familiar with IIS. But just wanted to know can it be done without IIS.

Comment: If you have it running on Visual Studio, and you won't care people accessing it via IP address (or get their hosts file changed), I think you can. But what's the point?