# ASP.NET development server: external access

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to run an ASP.NET MVC project on the development server, and then access it externally. I have set the port to be 8010 each time the development server runs.

Currently, it works fine if I go to `http://localhost:8010`. However, if I try to access it from a different computer on the network, via `http://128.11.53.104:8010` (where the middle bit is my computer's IP address), then it gives me the error: `HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid`.

What do I need to do such that the development server can be accessed externally? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASP.NET Dev Server will not accept connections issued by other computers because of security reason. I have had faced this kind of situation in the past and as a solution i have found [**This link**](http://web.archive.org/web/20100926083848/http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/jimw/archive/2009/09/03/accessing-the-visual-studio-asp-net-development-server-from-iphone.aspx).

Which tell us to use **“Trace Utility”**. Just check out that link. For other alternative solution, please check this [**SO Link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918/can-i-access-asp-net-development-server-in-an-intranet) and check the answer given by **Jon Galloway**.

Answer (score 4):

We made a free VS Extension to enable this, called Conveyor.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti

It doesn't modify any config files like some solutions.

Comment: Very nice plugin!

Answer (score 1):

The development server can only be accessed internally.

However you can set up a TCP forwarder that listens on another port and tunnels between that and your development server.

e.g. `http://128.11.53.104:8011`

I use tcpTrace for such things: http://www.pocketsoap.com/tcpTrace/